# Visual Studio adding extra lines when compiling a .dll?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have a C# project I'm playing with to create a DLL, but when I compile it and Visual Studio (2015 and 2017 do the same) creates the .dll, it adds extra variables and lines of code.

**Example line of C# code before being compiled:**

```
public OSDComputer GetOSDComputer(OSDGetComputerRequest ComputerInput)
{
    OSDComputer oSDComputer;
    try
    {
```

After the .dll gets compiled and I decompile it to read the output, it adds an extra variable that just references the existing one.

**Example of C# code after compiling:**

```
public OSDComputer GetOSDComputer(OSDGetComputerRequest ComputerInput)
{
    OSDComputer oSDComputer;
    OSDComputer oSDComputer1;
    try
    {
```

**Another example before compiling:**

```
catch
{
    flag = false;
}
return flag;
```

**After being compiled:**

```
catch
{
    flag = false;
}
flag1 = flag;
return flag1;
```

This type of thing doesn't seem harmful, but I would like to know if anybody knows why this happens?  It makes debugging difficult when there are extra lines of code inserted.

Comment: Try compiling in release mode.

Comment: Why are you debugging decompiled code?

Comment: How are you decompiling the code? It could simply be a bug in the deompiler. I don't really know why you would care about this? So long as it works as expected. Remeber dll's don't actually contain C# (or whatever) they are binary representations of your code

Comment: @SLaks Sorry, I probably should've provided more background.  There's an open source tool [here](https://scottkeiffer.wordpress.com/2016/09/15/configuration-manager-web-frontend-update-2-0/), which actually has a value pre-coded into one of the C# files that needs to be changed (that file is part of the .dll).  I used [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) to find out where the value lies, but even if I just decompile the original, create a VS project from it and compile it again (without making any changes), I get errors so I wanted to see why.

Comment: @Liam If I use JustDecompile on the source .dll, those extra lines of code don't exist, which makes me think it's not a bug in the decompiler.

Comment: Why don't you rebuild it from source?

Comment: I checked and it turns out it's not open source, it's just no longer maintained by the guy that created it (but by the time I realised, it wouldn't let me edit that comment).  Compiling in Release mode seems to have got rid of a bunch of the additional variables, but some are still there.  Could it just be the process of decompiling it and recompiling that could be buggy?

Comment: Decompilation isn't a perfect process because compilation is lossy. Decompiled code is never likely to match the source exactly.

Comment: @Liam Thanks mate; I think that's probably the best I can hope for at the moment.  I'll continue to see if the creator can release the source for me.

Comment: It's not "buggy", it's just that there are multiple possible interpretations of the IL. If you want to see what the code actually does, look at the IL directly. The motivation for this is still completely unclear to me, even after reading the comments. You are trying to decompile a DLL to which you do not have the source code, make changes, and then recompile it? You are not likely to experience success. The decompiler will serve you in an *advisory* capacity here, as you use it to rewrite the code from the ground up. Decompiling and recompiling is like creating a cow from a hamburger.

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks for your comment, I've contacted the creator again to see about getting the source code (as well as explaining what is broken). As far as the motivation goes - A feature of the tool doesn't work, and I found the code that needs changing in order to get it working, which was within a C# file within a library.  My hope was that (having no experience with DLLs before) I can decompile the code, change it to get the feature working and compile it up in a DLL again, but it sounds like that's a pretty unreliable way to approach it.